# Can django queryset date be formatted from 'DD:MM:YYYY HH:MM:SS' TO 'YYYY:MM:DD' using Func,Value,output_field?

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm

My desired output is :
{
" formated_date:'2021-05-01' ",
}

Queryset returns : {date : '2021-05-01 12:01:20'}

Comment: You mean in a form or within the qs itself?

Answer (score 1):

I got this working for MySql database:

```
queryset.annotate(release_date=
   Func(F('temp_date'),
   Value('%Y-%m-%d'),
   function='DATE_FORMAT',
   output_field=CharField())
```

Comment: also if you are using Postgres db,  use 'to_char' function and the format like this 'dd-mm-yyyy'

Answer (score 1):

Please *don't* do formatting in the database. Databases should store, manipulate and aggregate *data*, not present data in a nice format. Rendering data or providing it nicely is the task of a view, for example through a serializer.

You can use serializers, for example with:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date = serializers.DateTimeField(format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

or in the template with:

```
{{ value|date:"Y-m-d" }}
```